# Version Control System c#

Tags: c#, sql, version-control

I'm working on a C# app that uses SQL 2008 express. Sometimes I work at home and the most of the time at my office so there is no way to work in the same network. Everytime I change location, I need to save the project in my USB and update files in my home/office computer, so I find this a little bit frustrating.

Do you know a version control software which could let me do this without using my USB? something like SVN where I could only update my repository to have the most recent version? What about changes in the database? is there a way to keep this updated?

Comment: Sounds like you need some kind of remove VCS. Did you need Visual Studio integration? For database changes, consider either scripting & saving your schema changes, making full backups, or buy some hosting including SQL Server hosting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The scenario you describe is well covered by [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/) or [Git](http://git-scm.com/). You can use some online repository to store your work, like [GitHub](https://github.com/) or [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/). In any case you should create some strategy for of automatic deployment of the DB.

Comment: @krosegi I would prefer a distributed system for the scenarion Jorge describe

Comment: This is absolutely the way to go.  My preference is Mercurial/BitBucket as I find that Mercurial has better tools on Windows.  SVN is overkill in this scenario.  TFS stands for Terrible Flipping System IMHO so don;t even go there, unless you want all of you hair to fall out?

Comment: perfect it sounds like I would take a try on Mercurial, thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

There is plenty of free SVN hosting (google code for instance) if you don't care that it's open source.  There are plenty of SVN clients that integrate right into visual studio (One that I use and suggest would be AnkhSVN).  If you DB is on the local computer you're developing, you won't be much luck--but consider moving to a remote location.

Comment: in a near future I will to move my DB to a server, for now I'm working locally as possible. Thanks for your suggestion, I will take a look at AnkhSVN

Answer (score 1):

Just you? Try [dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/) and work from the same folder. It holds a 30-day history for free and syncs files automatically... It is much more convenient than source control for one user.

Comment: the dropbox schema sounds great as I am the only developer

Comment: it's hosted by a third party so it serves as a backup too :).

Comment: -1 a cloud folder with file history is not a VCS. Say you want to roll back to a particular version? Can't do it, not sensibly anyway.

Comment: @JorgeZapata with a fully fledged VCS as Git or Mercurial you have other benefits as a smart hystory of your changes and a lot more... check out tehse products descriptions

Comment: The OP effectively wants a replacement for a USB rather than VCS - albeit it may be a better solution in the general case. Dropbox is much more convenient and offers some added benefits.

Answer (score 1):

The version control just keep track of the changes in your repository(I would suggest you GitHub anyway) .For the DataBase if you script your database then you can put the script files into your repository and push them to the source control(you didn't say much about your DataBase strategy)

Comment: sometimes I need to alter tables, the data doesn't mind at all. I just only need to have same schema in both databases

Comment: You have to take care about this I mean you have to script your DataBase and put the script file under your source control
something like https://github.com/aaronpk/Launchpad/blob/master/scripts/database.sql

Answer (score 1):

You could combine dropbox with SVN.  Create your SVN repository at whichever location you work at more, then check the code out to your dropbox folder.  You can then work from both work and home without having to carry your files with you, and you can keep your code in source control.

You won't be able to commit or get latest from your off-location, but that shouldn't be a problem given that dropbox is going to automatically back-up your files for you.  Just make sure to do your commit first thing when you get to your main location.

Answer (score 0):

Some sort of publicly hosted source control like Github or Bitbucket may work, but honestly for things that I'm just hacking on in a few differnet places, I just use DropBox.  Store your working copy of hte project in a DropBox folder, and when you get home it's automagically synced.

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to host your own [gitolite](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/) - at work or via dyndns at home - and have your develop branch on that one. Maybe you already have a Team Foundation Server at work already, then you could use that one.